# Add value to a specific row in a table using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I want to add some value to a specific row in my table without having to reference the cell number

I have this

```
Dim LO As ListObject
Set LO = Sheets(1).ListObjects("table1")

LO.ListColumns("USER").DataBodyRange = "John"
```

However, this would repeat for every row in my table, how do I get it so its just a single row without having to specifically reference a cell if possible

Comment: Which specific row is it (e.g. right under the header, last row of the table, a newly added row)?

Comment: Sorry should have mentioned that, right under the header

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've narrowed down the relevant cells to the single USER column sans header. Just add your relative row number to DataBodyRange.

```
Dim LO As ListObject
Set LO = Sheets(1).ListObjects("table1")

'put 'John' in first row of USER
LO.ListColumns("USER").DataBodyRange(1) = "John"
```

Comment: This works great but just wondering if there is a way to do it without specifically having to mention a number beside DataBodyRange

Comment: No, you need a number to isolate a single cell for the same reason that you can fill a column with formulas by entering it into the range.